# Plotting two lines with different length in a same plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot two lines in a same plot in R. The length of these two lines are different. What I did so far is:

```r
L <- c(-1.87731736,-0.93904772, 0.09349034, 0.88211328, 1.62668827, 
       2.45229737, 3.29279521, 4.16821441, 5.07816932, 5.98971301, 
       6.92079292, 7.85341450, 8.74968222, 9.67036437, 10.59479955, 
       11.51243444, 12.46106635, 13.44241394, 14.40218939)

D <- c(-4.9618451, -4.6051702, -4.6051702, -4.5098600, -4.1997051, -3.1010928, 
       -1.5095926, 0.2207407, 1.6789640, 3.3577330, 5.1708419, 7.2888853)

leaves <- c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)

plot(leaves, D, type = "l", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
mtext("x-lab", side = 1, line = 3.5)
mtext("y-lab", side = 2, line = 2.5)
axis(1, xaxp = c(7,25,18), las = 0.1, labels = FALSE)
text(seq(7, 25, by = 1), par("usr")[3] -3, labels = lablist, 
     srt = 45, pos =3, xpd = TRUE, offset = 1.2 , cex = 0.75)
axis(2, yaxp = c(-10, 15, 5), las = 2)
leaves = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
           17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)
lines(leaves, L, type = "l", pch = 22, lty = 2)
legend(7, 15, legend = c("D", "L"), lty = 1:2, cex = 0.8)
lablist = as.character(c("7-11", "8-23", "9-46", "10-98", "11-207", "12-451", 
                         "13-983", "14-2179", "15-4850", "16-10905", "17-24631", 
                         "18-56011", "19-127912", "20-293547", "21-676157", 
                         "22-1563372","23-3626149", "24-8436379", "25-19680277"))
```

The problem is that the longer line would not appear in the plot completely. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You can control the x and y axis limits using `xlim` and `ylim` in your `plot` call

Comment: @bouncyball  Thanks

Comment: `plot(leaves,D,type="l",  xaxt="n",yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
     ylim = c(-5,15), xlim= c(5,25))` This will resolves your problem. You need to modify the axis to make it neat tho.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks, it works